# Converting List<List<object>> to List<List<string>>

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have a collection of `List<List<object>>`. I need to convert it to `List<List<string>>`.
This is what i tried,

```
List<List<object>> dataOne = GetDataOne();
var dataTwo = dataOne.Select(x => x.Select(y => y.ToString()).ToList()).ToList();
```

Is this method fine? Or is there any other best way to do it?

Is there anyway to automatically convert the list without iterating over it, or having the framework iterate over it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach is fine, you need to visit all the elements to convert them

however, a cleaner way to do this would be:

```
var dataTwo = dataOne.ConvertAll(x => x.ConvertAll(obj => obj.ToString()));
```